# Latest results from db

Tags: mysql, sql

I need display results from two joined tables only for the latest project. I have the following query:

```
  SELECT project.id,
         project.created,
         COUNT(DISTINCT events.user_id) AS cnt
    FROM project
    JOIN events ON (events.project_id = project.id)
   WHERE project.creator = $creatorID
     AND events.user_id != $creatorID
ORDER BY project.created DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

For some reason I keep on getting the first project... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track. It seems you're missing a `GROUP BY` clause for your aggregate `COUNT()`. Try this:

```
SELECT
  project.id,
  project.created,
  count(DISTINCT events.user_id) AS cnt
FROM project
  JOIN events ON (events.project_id = project.id)
WHERE
  project.creator = $creatorID
  AND events.user_id != $creatorID
GROUP BY project.id, project.created
ORDER BY project.created DESC,
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1: I missed that.  Relevant info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html